# Exceeding limits of static built-in array in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

**SOLUTION EDIT:**

**Undefined behaviour is not the underlying issue here. Check my comment for solution, since I could not post an answer after the question was closed.**

I am implementing a simple stack data-structure in C++. The capacity is static and included in the class template argument. Whenever I try to push onto the stack when it is full, I get no loud errors. Instead, the count is set to the number that is pushed onto the stack, and incremented by one.

code:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
class stack {
public:
    stack() : m_count(0), m_data{ 0 } {}

    // --- member functions ---
    const size_t& push(const T& value) {
        m_data[m_count] = value;
        m_count++;
        return m_count;
    }

    T pop() {
        m_count--;
        T temp = m_data[m_count];
        m_data[m_count] = 0;

        return temp;
    }

    T& peek() {
        return m_data[m_count - 1];
    }
    
    // --- capacity ---
    const size_t capacity() const {
        return N;
    }

    const size_t& size() const {
        return m_count;
    }

    const bool empty() const {
        return m_count ? false : true;
    }

    friend bool operator==(const stack& lhs, const stack& rhs);
private:
    T m_data[N];
    size_t m_count;
};
```

And running like this in `main`:

```
stack<int, 5> st;
for (size_t i = 0; i < st.capacity(); ++i)
    st.push(5);
std::cout << "Size of stack: " << st.size() << std::endl; // 5
std::cout << "Capacity of stack: " << st.capacity() << std::endl; // 5

st.push(93); // No visible error
std::cout << "Size of stack: " << st.size() << std::endl; // 94
std::cout << "Capacity of stack: " << st.capacity() << std::endl; // 5
```

Does anybody know what is going on here?

**Edit: Clarification of question**

Comment: "For some reason, whenever I push something onto the stack when the capacity is at max, the compiler stays silent" -- The compiler is not active while your program is running, is is only involved in creating your program. Therefore, it is unable to detect run-time errors, it can only detect compile-time errors.

Comment: If you want the function `stack::push` to report some kind of error when the stack is full, then you must implement this yourself, for example by adding the line `if ( m_count == N ) throw ( "stack already full" );` at the start of the function.

Comment: Could you give some insight on why you are asking this question? Is this homework? Because I can't think of any real world situation were you would need this (but maybe you have some specific situation?)

Comment: I figured out what happens, and it is not associated with undefined behaviour. Since ``m_count`` is declared after ``m_data,`` ``m_data[m_count]`` just refers to ``m_count,`` thus overwriting it. This is silent in this case because ``int`` can be converted to ``size_t.`` Switching around the variable declarations solves this.